# Coordinate rounding causes jerky animation in Processing

Tags: animation, 2d, processing

Consider the following sketch:

```java
float offset = 0.0;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
    smooth(8);
}

void draw() {
    stroke(0);
    background(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    translate(offset, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        line(i * 20, 100, i * 30, 400);
    }
    offset += 0.1;
}
```

If you run it, you will notice that the lines move in a jerky kind of way, and not smoothly as one would hope. I'm guessing this is probably due to Processing rounding coordinates. Has anyone encountered and solved these issues before? Is there anything I can do about it?

Basically: **how would I make this animation be smooth while keeping the animation speed?**

Answer (score 0):

Processing isn't really "rounding" anything. The problem is that there is no such thing as half a pixel.

Think about it this way: you start out with an X value of 30.0, which is at pixel 30. You then increase it to 30.1, which is still at pixel 30. Then 30.2 is still at pixel 30. This continues until you finally increase to 31.0, which is at pixel 31.

In other words, you're spending 10 frames on each pixel. That's why your animation looks jerky: the line spends 10 frames on a coordinate, then moves, then spends 10 frames on a coordinate, etc.

If you increase the offset increment to `.5`, then you spend less time on each pixel and your animation is smoother.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

**Edit:** The above is true for the default renderer. The `P3D` renderer seems to be better at sub-pixel rendering:

[image: p3d]

You might also try the `P2D` renderer, which seems to be better at sub-pixel rendering than the default renderer as well.

Comment: It's smoother but also faster. There's subpixel rendering and things like that. Sketch has no issues taking fraction pixel positions, for example: http://i.imgur.com/BRwqEEU.gif

Comment: @cwj I understand that there's subpixel rendering. The problem is that you're spending 10 frames on the same pixel.

Comment: True, but I don't want it to be on the same pixel. I want to somehow interpolate it so the animation doesn't appear as jerky. I was giving Sketch as an example because it does a good job at it.

Comment: @cwj The sub-pixel rendering depends on the renderer. See my edited answer.